# I'm looking for way to have an app apk auto download from Google play

Tags: android, html, download, apk, google-apps

I'm looking for way to have an app apk auto download from Google play triggered by a timer on a mobile friendly website.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: I really hope there is no way. And if there is, it should be patched.

Comment: Read as: "I'm looking for a way to automatically install malware onto Android devices so I can steal lots of data without the user ever knowing."

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't permit a web page to download any file without the user's permission. So auto triggering maybe/will not work.

Your best bet is to let the user open the link to your App or simply download the Apk.